# TikZ/PGF figures messed in DVI

Tags: tikz-pgf, viewers, dvi

I have a graph. This is my code.

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgf,tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,patterns}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \definecolor{ttqqcc}{rgb}{0.2,0,0.8}
    \definecolor{ffqqtt}{rgb}{1,0,0.2}
    \definecolor{ttqqff}{rgb}{0.2,0,1}
    \definecolor{uququq}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.25}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]

    \draw[->] (-3.63,0) -- (3.67,0);
    \foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
      \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) 
        node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
    \draw[color=black] (3.48,0.07) node [anchor=south west] { $x$};

    \draw[->] (0,-1.93) -- (0,5.57);
    \foreach \y in {-1,1,2,3,4,5}
      \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) 
        node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
    \draw[color=black] (0.06,5.19) node [anchor=west] { $y$};

    \draw (0pt,-10pt) node[right] {\footnotesize $0$};

    \clip(-3.63,-1.93) rectangle (3.67,5.57);
    \draw[pattern color=ffqqtt,pattern=north east lines,fill opacity=0.1, smooth,samples=50,domain=0:1.0] 
    plot(\x,{\x^4-4*\x^2+3}) -- (1,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[pattern color=ttqqcc,pattern=crosshatch,fill opacity=0.1, smooth,samples=50,domain=1.0:1.7320508075688772] 
    plot(\x,{\x^4-4*\x^2+3}) -- (1.73,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;

    \begin{scope}[xscale=-1]
    \draw[pattern color=ffqqtt,pattern=north east lines,fill opacity=0.1, smooth,samples=50,domain=0:1.0] 
      plot(\x,{\x^4-4*\x^2+3}) -- (1,0) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[pattern color=ttqqcc,pattern=crosshatch,fill opacity=0.1, smooth,samples=50,domain=1.0:1.7320508075688772] 
      plot(\x,{\x^4-4*\x^2+3}) -- (1.73,0) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \draw[smooth,samples=100,domain=-3.6342419080068153:3.665758091993186] plot(\x,{(\x)^4-4*(\x)^2+3});

    \fill [color=uququq] (-1.73,0) circle (1.5pt);

    \fill [color=uququq] (-1,0) circle (1.5pt);

    \fill [color=uququq] (1,0) circle (1.5pt);

    \fill [color=uququq] (1.73,0) circle (1.5pt);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

When I see the DVI output DVI, I have

[image]

And if I look at the PDF file, I have

[image]

Comment: tikz / pgf figures never look good when viewed as dvi. Convert the dvi to ps or pdf, and everything should be alright.

Comment: If I use Miktex 2.8, I can view the tikz / pgf figures  figures in dvi. I have just installed Miktex 2.9.

Comment: And this is file.log http://www.mediafire.com/view/?iffvz1xb9xe2zch

Comment: Here's a post that could work for you http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.miktex/10737

Comment: @Alex Can you make your comment into a full answer, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Tikz` and `pgf` figures are based on postscript specials, i.e., postscript code is embedded within the [`dvi` file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_independent_file_format). Most dvi-viewers can display only parts of this postscript code and the figures may look distorted or parts are missing. A few dvi-viewers, e.g. yap which is included in MiKTeX, call ghostscript to render the postscript code.

If you convert the `dvi` file to postscript with `dvips` or to PDF with `dvipdf` and open it with a ps- oder pdf-viewing program, you should see all figures in full beauty.

Answer (score 11):

if you were using yap to view the dvi output, the following might help.

go to yap, change `View->Render Method` from the default `Pk` to `Dvips`, then everything is normal without compiling again. the details are beyond me, though.

Comment: Extremly usefull answer