# strange preview latex problem with tikz and maketitle

Tags: emacs, preview

The following example does not produce the expected preview:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\title{a}

\maketitle

$a$

\end{document}
```

Instead of the inline math a whole page is displayed. However, if I remove one of `\usepackage{tikz}`, `\title{a}` or `\maketitle` it works ?!

Versions:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Arch Linux) (INITEX)
- Ghostscript 9.10 (2013-08-30)
- Auctex 11.87-1 (pacman Package)

UPDATE: This bug was [reported](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2014-03/msg00007.html) to bug-auctex.

Comment: I'd suggest to report this to the [`bug-auctex`](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-auctex) mailing list.  Issue `M-x preview-report-bug RET` in Emacs to get a minimal bug report with all necessary information.

Comment: I also just reproduced this independently. I am on Debian wheezy. With default versions of Tex Live (2012) and PGF/TikZ (2.10) on wheezy, this is not reproducible. However, with Tex Live 2013 (backported to wheezy) which includes PGF 3.0, this problem *is* reproducible. The problem may be PGF 3.0. I could try testing for this. Ghostscript is 9.05 for both, and I doubt it is implicated in this. If others can reproduce, I suggest adding your config information here.

Comment: @FaheemMitha  Uh, good to know it once worked, but it general `preview` and `TikZ` don't play nice together because `TikZ` doesn't work very well with DVI output (see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84182/31416).

Comment: @giordano I've not had a problem in general with pdflatex and preview (which afaik does not use DVI). I'm currently seeing two different bugs, but it seems this one at least had been reported earlier.

Comment: Also, for the record, the poster wrote "However, if I remove one of \usepackage{tikz}, \title{a} or \maketitle it works ?!" However, I don't think this is the case. It looks like there some kind of off-by-one error (possibly triggered by PGF). This looks as follows. One place where a preview should be is missing. That preview appears in the next "slot". Henceforth it looks like each preview snippet is one ahead of where it should be, and in my file, commenting out either \title or \maketitle doesn't fix that. Of course, my file is rather longer than the minimal example given.

Comment: Addendum: To be clear, if you comment out \title you also need to comment out \maketitle or you get an error.

Comment: Taking out PGF/TikZ fixes the problem, at least for the article class.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be caused by a bug in AUCTeX.