# DVI file can not be generated correctly using tikz

Tags: dvi, dvi-mode

I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows,calc,shapes,backgrounds,intersections,positioning} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\tikzset{
%Define standard arrow tip
>=stealth
}
\def\height{3cm}
\def\width{10cm}

\begin{document}

% create a shadow layer, so that we don't need to worry about overdrawing other things
\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}

\newcommand{\specnode}[7]{
\draw[line width=2pt,shade, top color=white, bottom color=blue!70,shading angle=0] (#1cm,#2cm)--++(#3*.8,0)--++(#3*.2,-.5*#4)--++(#3*-.2,-.5*#4)--(#1,#2-#4)--++(#3*.2,#4*.5) node[anchor=west, text width=#5cm,xshift=#6cm] {\parbox{#5cm}{\centering #7}}--cycle;

}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\normalsize,line width=1pt,node distance=.1cm]
\tikzset{nodestyle1/.style={draw,blue,rounded corners=10pt,anchor=west,minimum width=2.2cm, minimum height=3.5cm,font=\normalsize,text=black}}



%GRID
%+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
%\draw[white] (0,0)--(\width,0)--(\width,\height)--(0,\height)--(0,0);
%\draw[very thin,color=gray] (0,0) grid (\width,\height);
% \foreach \j  in {0,...,8.5} {
  %    \node[] at (\j,0) {$\j$};
%    }
    
% \foreach \j  in {0,...,6} {
  %    \node[] at (0,\j) {$\j$};
 %   }
%===================================================================
\specnode{0}{1.5}{4.5}{1.2}{2}{.1}{Background information}

\specnode{3.9}{1.5}{4.5}{1.2}{3}{-.2}{Pattern utilization and factors}

\specnode{7.8}{1.5}{4.5}{1.2}{3}{-.2}{Patterns\\ Documention}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I use `pdflatex` everything works:
[image]

, but I need to get `dvi` for publishing it in IEEE.

Why `latex` compiler does not work properly? I'm using `MIKTEX 2.9` with `TEXStudio`.

It gives me this error `Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support fadings.`

Comment: @Joseph Wright `dvips` doesn work either because of this error `Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support fadings.`

Comment: The message seems pretty clear: the `dvips` route doesn't support fadings : they can only be produced in direct PDF mode.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/tikz-pgf-figures-messed-in-dvi) QA. Out of curiosity, why do you need `dvi` for `IEEE`? Here in our lab, guys frequently submit to IEEE and everyone uses pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is essentially the answer: the `dvips` route does not support fadings. That is due to the differences between PostScript and PDF file formats: only the latter has native support for fadings. You will have to use the direct PDF route.