# Tikz works for pdflatex but not texlive

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been having issues with tikz, it's simply not outputting anything onto the page, I tried with circuitikz and default tikz examples off the internet, to no avail.

I then tried pdflatex (which I didn't know I had on linux mint) and it worked flawlessly, but that is not the default when I just type latex, it uses texlive.

I don't know if I want to change over to pdflatex (what are the disadvantages?) or how to change the default (I want to keep typing latex, not pdflatex).

Is it a known issue with texlive? IS there any way to fix it?

edit:

Here is a basic example that I took right off of the Tikz site, the exact one that would only work with pdflatex.

```
% A simple Tree
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz
% https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/latex-cookbook
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
  \node {Formulas}
    child { node {single-line} }
    child { node {multi-line}
      child { node {aligned at}
        child { node {relation sign} }
        child { node {several places} }
        child { node {center} } }
      child { node {first left,\\centered,\\last right} } };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could it just be that dvi format doesn't like the images?

Comment: TikZ work with LaTeX as well with pdfLaTeX. Provide minimal working example, that we can test it. TeX Live, it is (La)Tex distribution, It also contain LaTeX as well pdfLaTeX (between others.

Comment: `pdflatex`, `latex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex` are typesetting engines **all part of TeXlive**. `latex` typesets your file in `.dvi`, whereas `pdflatex` typesets your file directly in `.pdf`.

Comment: Your posted code compiles fine in `latex`.  There can be an issue with the program you use to view the `.dvi` file, but that is just a guess. Btw `texlive` is not a program, as Astrinus says, it is a TeX distribution that contains several different typesetting engines.

Comment: Andrew you are correct, a latex compiled to dvi and then converted to pdf works. Now to figure out what's wrong with my dvi viewer

Comment: TikZ is often seen to have problems with DVI, see e.g. [TikZ/PGF figures messed in DVI](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84182)