# TikZ doesn't work as expected

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.8]
    \node[draw]  (n1) at (0,0) {$a_0b_0$};
    \node[draw] (n2) at (2,0) {$a_1b_0$};
    \node[draw] (n3) at (4,0) {$a_2b_0$};

    \node[draw] (n4) at (0,2) {$a_0b_1$};        
    \node[draw] (n5) at (2,2) {$a_1b_1$};
    \node[draw] (n6) at (4,2) {$a_2b_1$};

    \node[draw] (n7) at (0,4) {$a_0b_2$};
    \node[draw] (n8) at (2,4) {$a_1b_2$};
    \node[draw] (n9) at (4,4) {$a_2b_2$};
    \draw [thick, <-] (5.2,0) -- (4.55,0);
    \draw [thick, <-] (0,5) -- (0,4.35);
    \node [right] at (5.2,0) {$A$};
    \node [above] at (0,5) {$B$};
    \draw (n1) edge[dashed] (n2);
    \draw (n2) edge[dashed] (n3);

    \draw (n4) edge[dashed] (n5);
    \draw (n5) edge[dashed] (n6);

    \draw (n7) edge[dashed] (n8);
    \draw (n8) edge[dashed] (n9);

    \draw (n1) edge[dashed] (n4);
    \draw (n4) edge[dashed] (n7);

    \draw (n2) edge[dashed] (n5);
    \draw (n5) edge[dashed] (n8);       

    \draw (n3) edge[dashed] (n6);
    \draw (n6) edge[dashed] (n9);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For this code when I run the PdfLaTeX, it is giving everything at same place without any gaps. What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `...{$a_0~b_0$}...`. Or where are you missing gaps?

Comment: The code seems to work fine here, are you sure you haven't generated a DVI-file, and that you're looking at that? (TikZ-diagrams typically doesn't work well in DVI I think, see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84182/tikz-pgf-figures-messed-in-dvi)

Comment: The code works also for me (Win10+MiKTeX) using both PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: Did you try the minimal working example yourself? Is there anywhere a `\tikzset{x=0,y=0}` in you complete code?

Comment: Can you put also `\pgfversion` in the body of the document somewhere to see the version?